# console.log is not printing to Debug Console in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-code, console, electron

I have created `launch.json` file exactly as [this](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/debugging-vscode) for debugging my Electron Application on VS Code. But the `console.log()` not printing anything to the debug console.

If I add  `"console": "integratedTerminal"` to `launch.json` the log displays on the built in terminal. I want the log to be displayed on debug console. How can I fix it?

Comment: it might be outputting log IN-APP: check your developer tools window inside the electron app

Comment: No, I put the logs in the main process, not in render process. So it has to be displayed in the debug-console on the code.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In the `launch.json` configuration you are using, add
`"outputCapture": "std"`

example

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "outputCapture": "std",
      ...
  }
  ]
}
```

Comment: it stopes to the breakpoint and it doesnt show the printed output on the console. However if I run without debug it prints the result normaly...

Comment: What is the significance of the version field, and is it necessary if you don't care to specify one?